# how to add new language search to advanced search page in moss 2007 through code?

Tags: sharepoint, search, new-operator

In Moss 2007 how to add japanese,portuguese,romanian languages through code.we can edit the xml and add the particular lcid for achieving the same.but how to make it through code.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get a reference to the advanced search box web part using SPLimitedWebPartManager. You'll probably need to set the property to your updated xml rather than setting something language specific.